# Mongoose populate and search by populated field

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am trying to do a simple search on a field that is a ref of another collection.  Say I have the example collection of Invoices with a reference to a collection named client.  So the example schema would look like so:

```
const invoiceSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  amount: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  client: {
    type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Client'
  },
}
```

Then I have the client schema like so:

```
const clientSchema = new Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
}
```

What I want to do is query the invoice schema and search for the name field in the client.

I have tried to use find and match with populate but that just returns the entire invoices collection and the client field is null on all of them:

```
const q = new RegExp(req.body.q, 'i');

invoices = await Invoice.find().populate({
    path: 'client',
    match: {
      name: q
    }
  });
```

So how should I go about searching for a populated field with mongoose?